# Solving UIStackView Layout Ambiguity

Tags: ios, uistackview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` that has the following elements:

- UIImageView
- UILabel
- UILabel

I want the `UIImageView` on the left, and the 2 `UILabel` objects stacked one on the other on the right side. Here's what it looks like in the storyboard:

[image: StackView]

I've got a **horizontal** `UIStackView`. Inside it is the `UIImageView` and a **vertical** `UIStackView`.

Here's what the hierarchy looks like:

[image: hiearchy]

For some reason, I'm getting warnings on ambiguity for the title and description labels. I've tried to tweak them again and again but I couldn't get it quite right. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the horizontal `UIStackView` containing your title and description pinned to anything?

Comment: Yeah, all 4 sides of superview

Comment: Do you want the title & description to fill vertically to the same height as your image view?

Answer (score 4):

Make the vertical stackview as fill equally

What I would do is to fix aspect ratio or size of image and make horizontal stack view as equally fill

If image size is variable then I would set the content hugging priority of image higher to the vertical stack view so that it displays entire image without cropping and vertical stack view with fill equally.